# How to handle RWD without disturbing the suggested structure

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

My specific HTML strucure in the unordered  list,

```
      <li key={index}>
        <img src={avatar} alt={title} />
        <div>
          <h2>
            <Trans>{title}</Trans>
          </h2>
          <p className="mb-0">
            <Trans>{desciption}</Trans>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    width: 584px;
    padding: 40px 56px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
img {
     width: 104px;
     height: 104px;
     margin-right: 24px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This gives me proper expected output(desktop view),

[image: for desktop view]

But now, I wanna achieve this(mobile view),

[image: mobile view]

So how to achieve the above mobile view without disturbing the structure?
Or how to structure it, so that only CSS changes will achieve both the results for desktop and then mobile view using media queries?

Things that I've tried(with and w/o changing the current HTML structure),

1. CSS3 grid
2. CSS3 flexbox
3. CSS3 multiple columns layout

but had to give -ve margins OR positioning, but the solution is not scalable, as the heading may occupy more than 1 line, length of the content may change. Even if I do the mobile-first approach, the same thing has to achieve!

Comment: If you do this without javascript, then it will turn out "crooked" and imperfect, because your description and title are in a separate div, relative to the picture. Although, if you really try, you can do it with the help of grid.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov: I tried with grid, but the para always starts at 2nd row, which is after image/h2, then have to give -ve margin/transform to move it up. But again, it's not scalable!

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov: You were right, I was adding span 2 values to para only, if I did it to image as well, it's working fine, as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works for you, as this one doesn't follow your html structure (not a major change, just removed one `div` tag.)

But also, the div which is parent of the `p` tag and the `h2` tag doesn't play any major role as per the CSS you have provided.

So I removed that div and made `h2`, `p` and `img` tag as the children of the grid.

I created this layout using both grid and media query. Media query enables the mobile view when you have `max-width: 480px`

```css
    body {
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .header {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        width: 400px;
        grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 10px 100px;
        grid-gap: 10px 20px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .image {
        grid-row: span 2;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .grid {
            width: 200px;
            grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 60px 100px;
            grid-gap: 20px 10px;
        }
        .image {
            grid-row: span 1;
        }
        .description {
            grid-column: span 2;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid">
        <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1084/1*L8UwJymGdpTh-jSXhDZO6g.png" width="100%" />
        <h2 class="header">Amplify Growth</h2>
        <p class="description">We provide a system that allows you to easily engage your customer and business with our marketing and loyalty programmes. Setup once and our system will do the rest.</p>
    </div>
```

The media query overrides almost all of the grid properties. But it gives the proper solution.

You can refer to this codepen link as well: https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/KKMrOBG?editors=1100